# Trying to figure out why image thumbnail isn't showing up when shared on timeline

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

Why would an image thumbnail not show up when I share a post on a facebook timeline? It used to work perfectly, now I'm not getting an image. Here is a sample link. (http://noahsdad.com/chris-burke-corky-life-goes-on/)

Thanks.

Comment: There's a '//' in the image path, is that valid?

Comment: @igy Hmm, not sure what you mean. Also Jon mentioned there was no og in my code, but when look, I see it. Are you seeing open graph code?

Comment: yes but the image URL has a '//' in the path, which seems odd

Comment: @igy Hmm. that is strange. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any open graph tags on your page there. In order for the image to show up properly, and to be able to curate which image gets posted on Facebook, the og:image tag should be used in the head of the document. Before you do that, you'll want to include the the  Open Graph name space in your html declaration.

An example is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
  ....
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/img/example.jpg" />
  ....
 </head>
```

where the example url points to the actual image you want to appear.

Once you've got that in place, you can test the link here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If you did it correctly, you should see the expected image show up in the debug validation results.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I like that page on Facebook, I do get an image of Chris Burke holding Noah in my timeline: http://dirtymitten.org/dirtyimages/stackoverflow-og-noah.png

Comment: Thanks for your help! Quick question, I see a thumb nail when I go to the debug mode for that post (it's also the same picture that showed up on your timeline.) I'm confused how there are no open graph tags on that page? Are you sure they aren't there? When I view source I see them.

Comment: I viewed source and didn't see them in the `<head>` tag. I see them in the body as optimized, like this: `http://ogp.me/ns#image`, which I haven't seen done before (optimized for Yoast).

Comment: I was expecting, and looking for, the basic open graph markup meta tags, as described here: http://ogp.me/#metadata